# get multiple dropdown values using emberjs

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am not able to retrieve the values from the dropdown box using emberjs. Actually if i use single selection box, i am able to retrieve the value, but if i select for the second dropdown, then the first dropdown box gets refreshed.
So in my code I am using 3 dropdown boxes and if i select 2nd or 3rd dropdown, previous dropdowns will get refreshed.
Here is my html code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Registration</title>


</head>
<body>

  <!-- ... Ember.js and other javascript dependencies ... -->   
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="">
  <form>
  Currency {{view Ember.Select content=name optionValuePath="content.value" value=content.value optionLabelPath="content.value" selectionBinding=currency}}
  Fuel Economy {{view Ember.Select content=name1 optionValuePath="content.value" value=content.value optionLabelPath="content.value" selectionBinding=fuel}}
  Date_Format {{view Ember.Select content=name2 optionValuePath="content.value" value=content.value optionLabelPath="content.value" selectionBinding=dateval}}


    <input type="button" {{action 'check' 77}} value="Hit Me" />
</form>
  </script>

  <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/handlebars-v1.3.0.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ember.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ember-data.js"></script>

  <script src="js/select.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Here is my JS code :

```
window.Format = Ember.Application.create();
Format.ApplicationController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

currency : null, 
fuel : null, 
dateval : null,                                                     
name: [{value:"USD"}, {value:"INR"}],
name1: [{value:"Kmph"},{value: "Mph"}],
name2: [{value:"dd/mm/yyyy"},{value: "mm/dd/yyyy"}],
actions: {
    check: function() {
        var currency = this.get("currency.value");
        var fuel = this.get("fuel.value");
        var dateval = this.get("dateval.value");

    }
}
```

});

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind the value of the select box to a property in your controller.

```
Currency {{view Ember.Select 
  content=name 
  optionValuePath="content.value"
  optionLabelPath="content.value"
  valueBinding=currency}}
```

Then you can access the value directly the property as `this.get('currency');`

[Here is a working bin.](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/tarew/1/edit)

Comment: Thats awesome..Finally it was worked for me and very much thank you.

Comment: Glad to help. Please set this as the answer.